# Не работают кнопки в python TeleBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

В никакую не работают кнопки

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot =  telebot.TeleBot('API')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def keyboard(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)
    buttons1 = types.inlineKeyboardButton1(text = 'Хочу стати учасницею клуба мам', callback_data = р1)
    buttons2 = types.inlineKeyboardButton2(text = 'Хочу стати партнером', callback_data = p2)
    buttons3 = types.inlineKeyboardButton3(text = 'Хочу стати вашим представником', callback_data = p3)
    buttons4 = types.inlineKeyboardButton4(text = 'Я мама блогер', callback_data = p4)
    buttons5 = types.inlineKeyboardButton5(text = 'FAQ', callback_data = p5)
    buttons6 = types.inlineKeyboardButton6(text = 'Про клуб', callback_data = p6)
    buttons7 = types.inlineKeyboardButton7(text = 'Хочу ознайомитись з вашими партнерами', callback_data = p7)
    buttons8 = types.inlineKeyboardButton8(text = 'Хочу приєднатися в чат мам свого міста', url='https://www.xmothers.com/contact/ )')
    buttons9 = types.inlineKeyboardButton9(text = 'Ми в соціальних мережах', callback_data = p9)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Текст персонажа', reply_markup = keyboard)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Множество раз удалял и ставил заново  pyTelegramBotAPI. telebot у меня не стоит. Уже не знаю, что делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Твой код не работает потому что `InlineKeyboardButton` это класс который находится где-то в модуле `telebot`, он имеет определенное имя и его не стоит коверкать как сделал ты. Также для того чтобы кнопки появились их нужно подсоединить к клавиатуре чего ты не сделал.

Попробуй этот код:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def keyboard(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    buttons = [
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Хочу стати учасницею клуба мам',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Хочу стати партнером',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Хочу стати вашим представником',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Я мама блогер',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='FAQ',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Про клуб',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Хочу ознайомитись з вашими партнерами',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Хочу приєднатися в чат мам свого міста',
            url='https://www.xmothers.com/contact/ )'
        ),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text='Ми в соціальних мережах',
            callback_data='your_callback_data'
        ),
    ]
    markup.add(*buttons)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Текст персонажа', reply_markup=markup)
```